# Yii - CGridview performance issue

Tags: memcached, apc, yii

Hello fellow developers,

I am currently running into severe delays when updating CGridview using an ajax button call (or a normal redirect or refresh), I can tell using firebug's console that the request itself takes about 399 MS which is not bad, but it goes down hill when the CGridview is updated, I'm talking about 3941 MS (or 4.3 sec) just to update the view, which to me is pretty terrible!

All Yii required extensions (such as Memcache, PDO MySQL and APC) are enabled. I also refered to using the caching method to solve this by adding :

```
 $dependency = new CDbCacheDependency('SELECT MAX(lu_date) FROM {{issues}}');
 return new CActiveDataProvider(Issue::model()->cache(3600, $dependency, 4), array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 20,
        ),
        'sort' => array('defaultOrder' => 'c_date DESC')
    ));
```

Unfortunately no improvements took place,
Note the I currently have more than 5 relations implemented and called in the CGridview using lazy loading. Can this be the issue in place? 
My current server is LAMP - Linux based

Thank you for taking the time to read this, any advices or opinions are greatly welcomed :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have 5 relations you are making 1+5*20 = 101 queries with lazy loading. 
You should try eager loading:

```
Issue::model()->with('relation1', 'relation2', 'deep.relation3')
```

Comment: Issue::model()->with('relation1', 'relation2', 'relation3','relation4','relation4')->cache(3600, $dependency, 5)
This what I did, I still can't seem to notice a difference, do I have to edit something in CGridviw also? the way relations are called?